# asp.net mvc nested view model form sumission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to only accept post back values from a nested view model?

For example, I would like to post only the 'Address':
`@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.User.Account.Address.Street)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.User.Account.Address.Street)`

To this controller action:`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress(Address address) {
  // save to db here
}`

Currently the values only post back if I pass the Address to it's own partial view so that the properties look like:`@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Street)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Street)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could specify the binding prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress([Bind(Prefix = "User.Account")] Address model) 
{
    ...
}
```

Another possibility is to use a partial:

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.User.Account.Address)
```

and inside `_Address.cshtml`:

```
@model Address
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Street)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Street)
```

Comment: Thanks, the Bind Prefix is exactly what I was looking for.